# How to handle post a BigInteger in JSONObject in grails controller?

Tags: json, grails

Here is my example:

```
class MyController {

    def index() {
        JSONObject json = request.JSON
        log.info('{}', json)
        respond json
    }

}
```

How do I handle BigInteger in json? like this:

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"largeNum": 99999999999999999999999}' http://localhost:8080/
```

The JSONObject will conver this `largeNum` to `Double` like this:

```
{"largeNum":9.999999999999999E22}
```

But I want to get a BigInteger, how to?

Comment: I'd use strings to transport BigDecimal/Integer since JSON numbers are doubles.

Comment: @cfrick: JSON numbers are not doubles. They don't have a limitation.

Comment: @Peter Won't help you if your producers/consumers might use the worst-case-scenario (double) and you end up with wrong numbers.  I prefer forcing them into submission to think about the problem.

Comment: @cfrick: Yes, that's right. I wanted to point out, that it's a matter which parser you use and not JSON itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. I push a PR to solve this issue: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/11334

Waiting the upstream to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the Grails JSON implementation.

The `request.JSON` calls the `grails.converters.JSON` which in turn uses the `org.grails.web.json.JSONTokener` class to parse the input.

The important code form `org.grails.web.json.JSONTokener#nextValue` is:

```
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    return Long.valueOf(s);
                } catch (Exception f) {
                    try {
                        return Double.valueOf(s);
                    } catch (Exception g) {
                        return s;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This will cause precision lost and there is no way to change the behavior,
because this tokenizer is used before a custom marshaller comes into play.

The only solution that comes into my mind is to use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

The code has been taken from `grails 3.3.0`. I don't know if that has been since than.

**About JSON Numbers:**
Without a concrete format, most json parsers in java will treat a json number as `BigDecimal`, because json numbers have no limitation and `BigDecimal` is the only java type to represent that correctly - see [JSON Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6)

This may seem awkward, because JSON stands for Java Script Object Notation and Javascript is not able to handle these numbers.

Comment: No. BigDecimal.valueOf(9.999999999999999E22).toBigInteger() is `99999999999999990000000`